# Contour Integral of $\int \frac{a^z}{z^2}\,dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

My task is to show $$\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{a^z}{z^2}\,dz=\begin{cases}\log a &:a\geq1\\ 0 &: 0<a<1\end{cases},\qquad c>0.$$So, I formed the contour consisting of a semi-circle of radius $R$ and center $c$ with a vertical line passing through $c$. I am having two problems. I can show that along this outer arc, the integral will go to zero if and only if $\log a\geq0$, or equivalently, $a\geq1$; the problem is that the integral of this contour should be $2\pi i\cdot \text{Res}(f;0)$, so for $a\geq1$, I find $$\int f(z)=2\pi i\log a,\qquad a\geq1.$$My second problem occurs when $0<a<1$, I can no longer get the integral along the arc to go to zero as before.

Am I making a mistake in my first calculation, or is the problem asking to show something that is wrong? For the second case, how do I calculate this integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a>1$, consider the contour $$(c-iT \to c+iT) \cup (c+iT \to -R +iT) \cup (-R+iT \to -R - iT) \cup (-R-iT \to c-iT),$$where $R>0$.

For $a<1$, consider the contour $$(c-iT \to c+iT) \cup (c+iT \to R +iT) \cup (R+iT \to R - iT) \cup (R-iT \to c-iT),$$where $R>0$.

Then let $R \to \infty$ and then $T \to \infty$.

The main reason for choice of these contours is that

- $a^{-R} \to 0$ for $a > 1$, as $R \to \infty$.
- $a^{R} \to 0$ for $a < 1$, as $R \to \infty$.

For $a>1$, the contour encloses a pole of the integrand at $z=0$ and hence this contribution will be reflected in the integral $\left( \text{recall that }a^z = 1 + z \color{red}{\log(a)} + \dfrac{z^2 \log^2(a)}{2!} + \cdots \right)$, whereas for $a<1$, the integrand is analytic in the region enclosed by the contour.

Comment: It turns out this is equivalent to Ron Gordon's answer, but the question about the value when $a\geq1$ still stands. Should the value be $2\pi i\log a$ or just $\log a$? I think the former is correct, but the WS has the latter.

Comment: It might be equivalent to Gordon's answer, I didn't read it when I was typing it out. To answer, your question, it should be $2 \pi i \log(a)$.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I kept getting, but I couldn't be sure if I made a simple error in calculation or not.

Answer (score 1):

For the case $a \in (0,1)$, as you say, the outer loop to the left of the vertical line of the original integral does not converge.  What you do then is close the loop to the right - in this case, you do not encircle any poles, so the integral over this circuit is zero; therefore, the  integral is zero.

For the case $a > 1$, the pole at $z=0$ is a double pole; the residue is computed as follows:

$$\text{Res}_{z=0} \frac{a^z}{z^2} = \frac{d}{dz} a^z|_{z=0} = \log{a}$$

The issue is that you forgot a factor of $\frac{1}{i 2 \pi}$, which is the definition of the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: Ah! Brilliant. What about the first case? Do you think I made a mistake or (Heaven forbid) my professor?

Comment: Wait, so with the last edit, are you claiming $\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{a^z}{z^2}\,dz=\log a$, as the professor puts? Or are you claiming that it instead is equal to $2\pi i\log a$, as I've put? I don't think I've forgotten a $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$ anywhere, so I'm seeking clarification.

Comment: I am claiming it is $i 2 \pi a$ as you put it.  To get the ILT, you divide by $i 2 \pi$ to get the sought result.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused. If we divide by $i2\pi$, we get the Inverse Laplace Transform (ILT)? I'm trying to figure this out, I'm sorry for being so slow about it. If we're both in agreement about the value of the integral, I'm happy. If there is a factor of $1/i2\pi$ that I've forgotten, I'd certainly like to learn from my mistake.

Comment: What I am saying is that you are correct.  But you are also clearly trying to compute the ILT (judging from the integral you posted) so I think either a) you prof is wrong, or b) you misinterpreted what he said and confused the integral with the ILT.

Comment: After reading Wikipedia, I see what you mean. The problem was written on a worksheet, so there isn't a chance I've misinterpreted it. Thanks for the information! I appreciate your patience :)